# use executeSQL() to populate portal in Filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I have a client with a Filemaker 16 app that uses an ODBC connection to a SQL Server DB. With Filemaker, everything I know about databases seems to be wrong. I have wrestled for 2 days with this and only ask as a last resort --- is it possible to populate a portal field with the results of a SQL query? I am trying to return unique records and exclude duplicates. Where would the executeSQL() call go? I thought perhaps in the Filter on the Portal, but that is not it. Sorry for the basic question.

Answer (score 0):

A FileMaker portal will always show the records matching a given relationship in the Relationship graph. This set of records can be further constrained by the portal filter.

To achieve a list of unique items, you will need to create a calculation field in your related table that determines if the record is unique. This can be done in many ways, ExecuteSQL being one. You can then use this field as a predicate in the relationship itself or use it in the portal filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one way to do it.

In the (shadow) table you want to display record from, create a calculation field that returned `1` if the record should be included and `0` if it should be omitted. It might be something like this:

```
Let (
  [
    _sql = List (
      "SELECT id" ;
      "FROM   table" ;
      "WHERE  match_field = ?" ;
      "ORDER BY id" ;
      "FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY"
    ) ;

    _id = ExecuteSQL ( _sql ; "" ; "" ; match_field )
  ] ;

  _id = id
)
```

Now in the table you want to show a portal from, create a global calculation field, `ONE` that returns `1` and then create a relationship between that table and the one you want to view a portal of using `ONE` and the SQL calc above as the match fields.

[image]

On a layout with a context into the `LAYOUT_CONTEXT` table above, you can create a portal into `SHADOW_TABLE`.